# RubyMine doesn't show rails source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

When I open the Gemfile inside RubyMine I can Ctrl+Click on every one of the gems and RubyMine will take me to the gem's source files. Except 'rails'..

In my current project it's

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13.rc2'
```

And I also can't see rails in the 'External Libraries' section.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the helpful information in [@zrl3dx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2291093/zrl3dx)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20595220/451710) I did the following:

Going to some external library in RubyMine to see where it's looking for source files. In my case it was in

`~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems`

Then I copied the railties directory to the rails directory

```
rmdir rails-3.2.13.rc2
cp -a railties-3.2.13.rc2 rails-3.2.13.rc2
```

Then RubyMine automatically detected the source code and I can happily Ctrl+Click once again :)

Comment: Edit: I can't edit it (page not found error on edit link) so I'll temporarily answer here. Except updating to rails 4 you can create symlinks from railties to rails and add some simple script, like 'system("bundle"); system(" link_folders")' because now after running 'bundle' you will lose changes. Probably it w'd be better to somehow wrap 'bundle' command with that, but currently I don't know how.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will probably try them after my next 'bundle' :)

Answer (score 0):

Rubymine is working fine, that's an 'issue' with Rails itself. Unfortunately, I don't have enough knowledge to say it for sure, but I suppose `Rails 3.2.x` folder is just a stub. I've tested that in my projects and indeed, project using `Rails 3.2.13` have empty rvm `rails-3.2.13` dir. I've downgraded it few times and `rails-3.1.12` contains a single file `rails.rb` which just requires `railties-3.2.1/lib' where whole Rails are.

I have also another project using `Rails 2.3.5` and there `rails-2.3.5` contains Rails files, I have also another one using `Rails 4.0.2` (why work with one project if you can work with few? ;)) where `rails-4.0.2` dir contains only guides.

So, to answer your question: Rubymine sees empty `rails-3.2.13.rc2` dir so it can't show you its source. To look into Rails source open `railties-3.2.13.rc2/lib/rails` directory.